# Node isometric tile map render second layer problem

Tags: node.js, tiles, isometric

I'm building an isometric map tile image in Node and I'm stuck at the second layer rendering, I can't figure out how to adjust items in the y axis

Here's my code so far:

```
let i = 0;
for (let layer of map) {
  const xTiles = layer.length;
  const yTiles = layer[0].length;

  for (let Xi = xTiles - 1; Xi >= 0; Xi--) {
    for (let Yi = 0; Yi < yTiles; Yi++) {
      const imgIndex = layer[Xi][Yi];
      if (imgIndex == null || imgIndex == -1) {
        continue;
      }
      const tile = tiles[imgIndex];

      const offX = (Xi * tileColOffset / 2 + Yi * tileColOffset / 2 + originX) + (i * ((tileColOffset - tile.width) / 2));
      const offY = (Yi * tileRowOffset / 2 - Xi * tileRowOffset / 2 + originY) - (i * ((tileRowOffset / 2)));

      ctx.drawImage(tile, offX, offY);
    }
  }
  i++;
}
```

I can center the sprite on the x axis but not on the y one, probably because sprites have different heights. The code above reproduces this

[image]

As you can see the taller sprites are quite centered, but the small ones are not. Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out that I have to calculate the difference between the half height of the ground tile and the height of the sprite:

```
let i = 0;
for (let layer of map) {
  const xTiles = layer.length;
  const yTiles = layer[0].length;

  for (let Xi = xTiles - 1; Xi >= 0; Xi--) {
    for (let Yi = 0; Yi < yTiles; Yi++) {
      const imgIndex = layer[Xi][Yi];
      if (imgIndex == null || imgIndex == -1) {
        continue;
      }
      const tile = tiles[imgIndex];

      let offX, offY
      if (i === 0) {
        offX = (Xi * tileColOffset / 2 + Yi * tileColOffset / 2 + originX);
        offY = (Yi * tileRowOffset / 2 - Xi * tileRowOffset / 2 + originY);
      } else {
        offX = (Xi * tileColOffset / 2 + Yi * tileColOffset / 2 + originX) + (i * ((tileColOffset - tile.width) / 2));
        offY = (Yi * tileRowOffset / 2 - Xi * tileRowOffset / 2 + originY) + ((i * (tileRowOffset / 2 - tile.height)));
      }
      ctx.drawImage(tile, offX, offY);
    }
  }
  i++;
}
```